# SQL Server: what are the roles to allow a user to give access to another login to a database he owns

Tags: sql-server

Since I'm not getting any traction with this question, I'm simplifying it:

Is it possible to associate a user to a db I own without having the db_securityadmin server role ?

---

original question:

I have login L1 associated to user U1.

L1 has server role `db_creator`.

I also have login L2

L1 has created DB1, and is dbo on it, and want to give access to L2. But unless the sysadmin gives L1 SECURITYADMIN server role, L1 cannot see L2.

So what is the setup to allow a `db_creator` to give access to other logins to his database ?

I'm a teacher, and I want to ask my student to create their DB and give access to some part of it to other students. But I don't want to give them securityadmin role.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case the user LA would be be considered as a schema. So on that assumption here's the code to grant select commands on L1, by L2.

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: L1 TO L2 WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This should be enough. Let me know if this isn't what you want.

Comment: The problem is that L1 doesn't see L2 (it's not in the list of visible connection). I don't want to do it as a sysadmin login, I want that L1 gives access to L2 directly, without asking for a sysadmin to help. If I grant securityadmin to L1, than it sees L2... but that's way too much power.